# How can I trigger an action after an OCaml printf with user-supplied format string

Tags: logging, ocaml, printf

I have a simple function that prints a string and exits:

```
let fatal s = 
  print_string "Log: ";
  print_endline s;
  exit 1
```

I can use printf to do something similar without the `exit 1`:

```
let log fmt = 
  printf ("Log: " ^^ fmt)
```

This log function takes a format string and returns a function that takes the parameters needed for that format string and prints "Log: " in front. (Of course my prefix isn't this simple for my real application.)

Taking these two and combining them is not easy.  A first attempt:

```
let fatalf fmt =
   Printf.printf ("Log: " ^^ fmt) 
   ???
   exit 1
```

The problem is that I have to return the result of my `printf` expression so that the remaining arguments can be applied to it.  Once I've returned this value, I don't have flow control anymore to run `exit`.

The printf formatter `%t` looks useful, as it takes a function and runs it:

```
printf ("Log: " ^^ fmt ^^ "%!%t") ... (fun _ -> exit 1)
```

This doesn't seem to work as the `%t` must be last so it's run after the log message is written, but this means that the exit function must be after user-specified parameters, and since there's no way to know how many parameters there will be intervening, one can't generate a closure that does the full application of printf when given the intervening arguments.

I recall there being some support for named printf arguments, but that this was pulled as it was buggy.  Is there any way to emulate that, or to achieve the desired "exit after arbitrary printf" behavior?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for `Printf.kprintf`:

```
let fatalf fmt =
  Printf.kprintf (fun str ->
    Printf.eprintf "Fatal error: %s !\n%!" str;
    exit 1) fmt
```

`kprintf` takes a continuation with type `string -> 'a` and applies it to the result of `sprintf`-ing with the supplied format. The result of the continuation is the result of the entire call, as expected.

Comment: This with `failwith` to compose a `failwithf` has been immensely helpful to me over the years. It should be noted that the parameter, `fmt` must be present else the type is inferred to be weakly polymorph. This exact example is presented, http://camltastic.blogspot.com/2008/09/writing-printf-like-functions.html

Comment: @nlucaroni, I'd advise against encoding too much information in the exception string. It is somewhat cumbersome but better in the long way to use custom exception types.

Answer (score 1):

`printf` is a tricky part of OCaml because it's supported by compiler magic.  If the source contains a string *constant* and its type environment requires a `printf` format, the compiler magically converts the string constant to a format.  This is pretty slick, but once you pass beyond the simplest uses you sometimes need to do the magic yourself.  In particular, note that it has to be a string *constant* in order for the compiler to be able to enforce strong typing.

Your second example doesn't show an `s` parameter, but I figure you just left it off.  If you just want to print one parameter using a format that's also passed as a parameter, you can do something like this:

```
let fatalfs f s =
    printf ("Log:" ^^ f) s;
    exit 1
```

The `^^` operator concatenates two formats into one format.

Here's a session with this function:

```
$ rlwrap ocaml312
    Objective Caml version 3.12.0

# let fatalfs f s = Printf.printf ("Log: " ^^ f) s; exit 1;;
val fatalfs :
  ('a -> 'b, out_channel, unit, unit, unit, unit) format6 -> 'a -> 'c = <fun>
# fatalfs "Here is the value: [%s]\n" "value";;
Log: Here is the value: [value]
$ echo $?
1
$
```

Note that fatalfs is actually polymorphic in the type of the parameter s.  It works as long as the type of the format string and the second parameter match up.  It's pretty impressive.

Comment: This restricts the user of this function to single-parameter format strings.  I didn't leave off the `s` parameter in the second example because I don't know how many parameters the user's format string will take, and don't want to fix this ahead of time.